# Retraction and extension

Tags: general-topology

first I will clarify some concepts

A continuous function $r$ from $X$ onto a subsspace $A$ of $X$ is a retraction iff $r\mid A$ is the identity on $A$.  The subspace $A$ of $X$ is then called a retract of $X$

help i need to try the following

1. A retract in a Hausdorff space is closed set
2. A subset $A$ of $X$ is a retract of $X$ iff every continuos function $f:A\longrightarrow Z$ has an extension to a continuous fuction$F:X\longrightarrow Z$

any suggestion is welcome

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is exactly the set on which the two continuous functions $r: X \to X$ and $\textrm{id}: X \to X$ coincide. As $X$ is Hausdorff, this set is closed by a standard theorem.

One direction of 2: If $r$ is the retraction, use $F = f \circ r$ as an extension of $F$. For the converse: extend $i_A: A \to X, i_A(x)=x$ and conclude we get a retraction.

Comment: $F = f \circ r$.

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, thx for spotting the typo.